# tf.app.run() AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I changed  tf.app.run() to tf.compat.v1.run() , but did not help.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # tf.app.run()

    tf.compat.v1.run()
```

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1' has no attribute 'run'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You need to initialize a session first: `with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess: sess.run(...)`

Comment: @ cs95 thank you , and now i got some feedback       : I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-06-28 08:51:31.764857: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f9c07a573f0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-28 08:51:31.764871: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version